# 4-month old wants to be outside carried all time

Tags: infant, crying, play-time

My 4-month old wants constantly being held outside? I have a hard time keeping him interested indoors even though we have a baby play-mat, baby inclined seat, baby hammock. Nothing works more than couple of minutes. It works a bit when i sing him songs and interact with him, but very soon starts shouting/crying and asking to go out. So i carry him out in a carrier. He is also not a fan of the stroller.

I guess kids of this age can't be reasoned with, any advice what to do?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Parenting SE! At the moment it is a little unclear to me as to what exactly do you want to do anyway. Are asking us how to make him want to be carried inside?

Comment: Thank you, I was about to ask the exact same question with a 17 month old daughter.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter It would be nice if he could be playing inside a bit. I hear from my friends their kids are able to sit (as long as mom is talking to them), or just be on tummy and look around and be content. But when i try this with my son he starts being bored in few mins and shouting starts.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of time it looks to me like every time he started shouting, he was actually sleepy, and i didn't realize that on time. And he would already be even in a too annoyed mood to fall asleep easily.

I started more following sleep cues, and calming him down first in a quiet room, and then giving him breast to make him fall asleep.

And now for us this works nicely. :)